# How to repeat sequence number many time? - odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Normaly seqeunces are made to make an incremention in any new record but what i'm looking for is to repeat the same number many times for exemple :

Record 1 : sequence = 1

Record 2 : sequence = 1

Record 3 : sequence = 2

Record 4 : sequence = 2

Record 5 : sequence = 3

Record 6 : sequence = 3

PS : Using one and the same sequence each time

Comment: but what logic or condition  you depend on to change the sequence number. for example every two record increment the sequence...

Comment: Exactly this is logic

Comment: Hope you give the right condition to make this logic:

Answer (score 0):

I have used same sequence for creating two records by following way ,

```
        name = self.env['ir.sequence'].get_id(amount.sequence_id.id)

        vals = {
            'name': name,
            'date': date,
            'ref': code,
            'amount' : line.amount,
            'period_id': period_id.id False,
            'journal_id': journal_id.id,
            }

        created_move_ids= self.create_move1(line,context,move_obj,created_move_ids,**vals**,date,period_ids)

        created_move_ids= self.create_move2(line,context,move_obj,created_move_ids,**vals**,date,period_ids)
```

I am passing same vals to both method , which contains same sequence in **name** field .

Comment: I just want to repeat the value 2 or 3 time i don't want that the sequence do the incrementation until he pass 2 or 3 or any number of records

Comment: for that, you can take the new field in "General Settings"  and set the value 2 or 3, so the system will use the same sequence for 2 or 3 times.